# Script to copy data and format/styling of whole columns to a new tab (same sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting, string-formatting, copy-paste

I have a spreadsheet with a Main tab containing columns A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P
I have specific formatting for those columns that can vary from column to column and line to line: colors, background colors, bold, italic, vertically centered in cell, horizontally centered/left/right/ aligned, etc…

I want to create other tabs and be able to select which columns I want in those. Example tab "Specific 1" with columns A,C,M,N, tab "Specific 2" with columns A,B,G,J,O,P, …

I have tried to copy/paste this`={'tab name'!A1:A}` in the first line of a new tabs' column, it imports the data but not the format.

I've found many topics and tried many times but it's most of the time about different spreadsheets and not the same one…

Does anyone know how I can do that?

EDIT : I need a script because I might have many copies of the columns in many tabs so I can't manually copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

- click here:

  [image: 0]
- press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`C`**</kbd>
- select desired sheet
- click this again

  [image: 0]
- right-click it and choose:

  [image]

Comment: I update the spreadsheet quite often and I might have a lot of tabs so I'd prefer to have an automatic solution where the content of other tabs update based on the content of the Main tab (which is the case with `={'tab name'!A1:A}`). Thx.

Comment: in that case you will need a script

Answer (score 0):

You musn´t write long script. For your problem enought recording macro and play with keybords shortcut or add conditon new.spredsheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgUtl.png)

Comment: Thanks for the information but I am not sure what to do with it. Do you have more details on how it could solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SpreadsheetApp functions [1], in order to achieve that you can use:

1) `openById` function [2] to get the Spreadsheet.

2) `getSheetByName` function [3] to get the sheet/tab.

3) `getRange` function [4] to get the source range.

4) `copyFormatToRange` function [5] to copy the format from source range to your destination range.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns

[5] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#copyformattorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend